# Location Menu Post/Get cache?

Tags: php

I have this menu setup and on the following page I grab the location that was chosen using the POST method. After navigating past the next page and attempting to go back it gives an error "ERR_CACHE_MISS". I know this is happening because once going past that page I lose the POST data but still am unsure of how to solve this problem.

```
<div id="container" class="container  justify-content-center">

  <form action="mix_menu.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal justify-content-center">
  <div class="selectWrapper">


  <select type="text" name= "location" >
  <option value="loc1">Location 1</option>
  <option value="loc2">Location 2</option>
  <option value="loc3">Location 3</option>
  <option value="loc4">Location 4</option>
  <option value="loc5">Location 5</option>
  <option value="loc6">Location 6</option>
  <option value="loc7">Location 7</option>
  <option value="loc8">Location 8</option>
  <option value="loc9">Location 9</option>
  </select>

</div>
<br>

    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <div class="offset-sm-auto text-center">
        <button class="btn-lg" type="mix-submit">Authorize</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

I'm grabbing the POST like this on the next page

`$storename = $_POST['location']`

Comment: Normal navigation should not happen via POST in the first place. If this is supposed to be part of the normal navigation of your site, do it via GET. If it is supposed to be some sort of "store selector", then it could also be acceptable to keep using POST, but store the value into the session then, so that you have it available on subsequent pages.

Comment: It is a sort of store selector. I swapped it to GET. Following up with that. I'm still fairly knew with PHP and studying how would I store this data to session so that subsequent back and forth through pages beyond still have this selected store. Would it be better to link it to database or just store it to session. How would be best to go about this?

Comment: Session should be sufficient. Unless you might perhaps rather want to transport this information via the URL to begin with. For example if you want search engines to index data from different stores easily, that could make more sense.